# How to dynamically tell if windows or forms authentication is used

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authentication

In my web application I need to take different actions depending on the type of authentication used. The application is designed and build to support both windows and forms authentication and the switching between the two is done directly from IIS.

At the moment I check if, at the start of the session, the name of the user is stored in `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name`. If the `Name` property is empty, then forms authentication is used; if not, then the property holds the name of the currently logged in winuser.

Is there a better way of dynamically checking the type of authentication used?

Comment: Both your current solution and the overall aim seem brittle. If possible, the *method* of authentication should be completely divorced from authorization decisions. E.g. under windows authentication, the users groups are used to assign roles. Whereas Forms authentication (by default) assigns no roles - can you not require specific group membership and test for role membership instead?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, unfortunately we cannot enforce such authentication rules on the clients. Regarding our aim, we try to keep the software as flexible as possible, while the (possible) clients come with different requests regarding the type of authentication used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check what *type* of principal `HttpContext.Current.User` is returning. If windows authentication is being used (directly) then it should be a [`WindowsPrincipal`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.windowsprincipal%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) as opposed to a [`GenericPrincipal`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.genericprincipal%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (which is, I believe, what Forms Authentication will set up).

If you're supporting more complex authentication schemes (e.g. ADFS) then it'll probably just be some other form of `ClaimsPrincipal` (which both of the above derive from).

Comment: There is the possibility of mixed authentication, based on licensing protocols. Nevertheless, windows authentication is the primary authentication method and checking the principal type provides the best solution for my problem. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2):

You can check the value returned by the [property FormsAuthentication.IsEnabled](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.isenabled%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Just a word of warning - this may satisfy the OPs requirement where *either* Windows Auth or Forms Auth is in play - but it wouldn't help in a mixed authentication scenario where multiple authentication methods are supported. This just tells you whether Forms is one of the possible methods, not what any particular user has used.

Comment: I changed the accepted answer since the solution provided by Damien has a greater degree of flexibility in the context of my application. +1 for a quick, simple and correct solution.